# Removing redudant sorting code

Tags: sorting, knockout.js

I am sorting my data in following way. I am using knockout observable

```
self.myObsArray1 = ko.observableArray();
self.myObsArray2 = ko.observableArray();
var sortData = false;

self.myObsArray1 .sort(function (a, b) {

                        if (sortData ) {
                            return (a.Name() < b.Name() ? -1 : (a.Name() > b.Name() ? 1 : 0));
                        }
                        else {
                            return (b.Name() < a.Name() ? -1 : (b.Name() > a.Name() ? 1 : 0));
                        }
 });
```

I am same type of above code in my page but with different column names like above i am using `Name` column for sorting.

Then i have same type of above code like above

```
self.myObsArray2 .sort(function (a, b) {

                        if (sortData ) {
                            return (a.Id() < b.Id() ? -1 : (a.Id() > b.Id() ? 1 : 0));
                        }
                        else {
                            return (b.Id() < a.Id() ? -1 : (b.Id() > a.Id() ? 1 : 0));
                        }
 });
```

Can we somehow remove this redundant code?

Comment: When optimisation comes in question, the first thing you need to ask yourself is, *what* do you want to optimise? Execution time? Memory usage? The amount of code written? Understandability? Pin pointing the problem narrows down the solutions.

Comment: If amount of code written is a concern, then you can refer to http://ryanrahlf.com/sorting-tables-by-column-header-with-knockout-js-part-2/ for ideas based on the principle  "access properties of a JavaScript object as if it were an associative array"

Comment: @Ian2thedv i changed title of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper function to create the sorter, thus making your code DRYer:

```
function createColumnSorter(column) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = a[column]();
        var valB = b[column]();

        if (sortData) {
            return (valA < valB ? -1 : (valA > valB ? 1 : 0));
        } else {
            return (valB < valA ? -1 : (valB > valA ? 1 : 0));
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
self.myObsArray1.sort(createColumnSorter('Name'));
self.myObsArray2.sort(createColumnSorter('Id'));
```

Comment: Sorry Module was typo. corrected my question. will try your answer now

Comment: Its not sorting properly

Comment: @Happy Can you be a bit more specific? The result should be exactly the same as with your previous code (without the "Module" typo of course).

Comment: The sorting is not working correctly because sortData variable is sometimes getting true and false. I have declared sortData variable at top of my model.

Comment: Then create a parameter for it: `function createColumnSorter(column, sortData)`, and call it like this: `self.myObsArray1.sort(createColumnSorter('Name'), sortData);`

Comment: i did created parameter and passed it like this self.myObsArray1.sort(createColumnSorter('Name', true));
but somehow not working

Comment: sorry was doing something silly. Corrected myself. Many thanks. Its working